# Authenticating any Linux distro with Tacacs and Active Directory

Tags: linux, active-directory, tacacs+

I have a set-up in my organisation where in, login to all network devices (Cisco, Juniper & ....) are authenticated using Windows AD and Cisco tacacs server. User's are pushed into AD via separate web portal.

Now, I have a requirement of integrating all Linux servers to above set up. How can I achieve above requirement?

I did bit of research from my end and found that it is possible to integrate Linux with TAC server but one needs to manually add all users to Linux in a tac config file. I don't want to do manual adding stuff and want AD to play that role. Is it possible to do?? Can anyone help me with the steps to do so????

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm confused - are you looking to authenticate against AD or tacacs?

Comment: Tacacs will forward authentication request to AD (TO VERIFY) and other two AA's will happen at tacacs (i.e. Authorization and Accounting).....If I am making user entry in AD, I don't want that to be done at every Linux(This step I want to get rid off)......Are you clear now??? Andy